# can i split my Stored procedure into two like this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Since i got error  error when I try to run a stored procedure from mvc project which return multiple result sets i decided to split my Sp like this :
I am using Entity Framework database-first approach.

**This was my original stored procedure :**

```
  Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspMarket_test]
@UserID INT OUTPUT,
@Session VARCHAR(36)
  AS
  BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP 1
        FirstName, LastName, grant
    FROM dbo.test_Users AS U
    WHERE
       U.userID = @UserID 
       AND CAST (U.userHashKey as varchar(36)) = @Session;

    select
       GS.Account, GSA.Permissions
    from user_name GS 
    Inner join user_name_Apps GSA on GS.ID = GSA.ID
    where GS.UserID = @UserID

    UPDATE dbo.test_Users 
    SET grant = 0
    WHERE
     userID = @UserID
     ;

    END
```

Now i split this into two like this :

```
   USE [Tracker]
   GO
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO

   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  GO

   Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Market_Scope]
@UserID INT OUTPUT
  AS
    BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT TOP 1

       GS.Account, GSA.Permissions
     from user_name GS 
     Inner join user_name_Apps GSA on GS.ID = GSA.ID
       where GS.UserID = @UserID
 ;
          END
           GO
```

2nd SP is :

```
    USE [Tracker]
   GO
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO

   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO

   Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Market_Users]
          @UserID INT OUTPUT,
        @Session VARCHAR(36)
        SELECT TOP 1
       FirstName, LastName, grant
        FROM dbo.test_Users AS U
     WHERE
      U.userID = @UserID 
     AND CAST (U.userHashKey as varchar(36)) = @Session;
    UPDATE dbo.test_Users 
     SET grant = 0
    WHERE
    userID = @UserID
     ;

    END
     Go
```

Now i am calling these two SP like this in my class :

```
     public void permissions(string sess)
    {
        using (var ctx2 = new Tracker_Entities())
        {  
       ctx2.uspMarket_Users(new ObjectParameter("UserID", typeof(int)), sess);
       ctx2.uspMarket_list(new ObjectParameter("UserID",typeof(int)));
       ctx2.SaveChanges();
        }
      }
```

This is how i calling in controller :

```
  public ActionResult Index(string sess)
    {

        var permissions = new Accept();
        permissions.permissions(sess);



        return View();
     }
```

since both SP just selecting records what i did is i populated dummy data into my user_name_apps table. So how do i  check in front end whether this SP executing properly or not? I can execute in my sql server and it is working fine there.But i want to make sure i am calling my SP correctly. So how can i do this ?

Comment: Your stored procedure is returning more than one result set - Entity Framework cannot deal with that (yet).

Comment: @marc_s so what is the best solution for this now? can you help me in splitting this into two SP where it returns one result set per SP? is this the best solution for me?

Comment: @marc_s actually as of EF5 model/database first supports stored procs with multiple resultsets

Comment: @Raj In both Translate calls the entity set name is "Tracker_Entities". I don't know how your model looks like but I think `Users_list` and `users_details` entities are in different entity sets and therefore you can't use "Tracker_Entities" in both calls.

Comment: @Pawel I used Tracker_Entities for both because both user_lists and user_details are in this database. when i try to run i am getting exception here :  var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); .It is pointing here and telling that "@UserID" is not supplied. Can you just tell me whether i am passing parameters in exact place. I have used the exact steps which i used to do to retrieve single result sets. So i have doubts here..

Comment: `.ExecuteReader` fails because you did not pass the parameter. You need to set the parameter before you call `.ExecuteReader`. You need to add the following line `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", {actual user id value});` before you call `.ExecuteReader`. I believe this will make the ExecuteReader work but then the translate will fail due to the issue I wrote about above. Can you show your model?

Comment: @Pawel you mean i need to show code of my model? i used database first approach and there is lots of code since there are plenty of tables and SP. so i don't know how i can show my code here. Instead of all this can i split my SP into two, so i can return one result set in each SP? can you help me in how to achieve this for above SP?

Comment: @Raj I would use EDMX file instead, it would make it easier using function import, also you should return only one result set, you can use variable table to achieve that

Comment: @Raj - show only the two entity types and corresponding entity sets from CSpace.

Comment: @Pawel I dont understand your question.I AM using only one entity that is Tracker_Entities because both table test_user and user_name are in this database.I updated my table name in SP, have a look into that.I am using IObjectContextAdapter two times assuming i have two select statements and this is the way to call for two resultsets. Am i right?

Comment: @Pawel i UPDATED my solution. I split my SP into two and i called that.Is it okay to call like this?

Comment: @Raj looks good to me

Comment: @Raj You seem to be using two entities - test_user and user_name and "Tracker_Entities" seems to be your context. Entities in EF belong to entity sets. This is not very visible but in case of `Translate` it is important. If you have an edmx you can look inside and you will see entity sets and and they will have the entity type. AFAIR, in CodeFirst the EntitySet name are just the names of a DbSet properties on the context.

Comment: If you are using .NET 4.5 and you have an EDMX, [EF can return multiple result sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx).

Comment: @DannyVarod Hi first i tried to follow returning multiple result set.But i dont know what mistake i am doing i am getting exceptions.I will update my post.can you just have a look into that and correct me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: On which of the two quarries do you get an exception? Or is it only when you use the big SP? Did you map the result sets like in the MSDN link I posted?

Comment: @DannyVarod when i use two separrate procedures i am not getting errors.But when i debug and check its not showing results.It is just showing count=0 inside my table. I populated dummy data and now for permissions it should show 0 or 1 which is bit. but its not showing.can you spot any error on calling this SP.I updated my post.Check how i am calling my SP class in controller.

Comment: Add a screenshot of the mapping of both versions.

Comment: I am not using any mapping? I just wrote code what i posted. what exactly you mean?